# Sketch 3 - detaching a symbol leaves items within folder still linked

Tags: sketch-app

I'm using the BootSketch 3 symbol library for Sketch 3, and want to edit the color of one instance of a glyphicon. However, even after I detach that instance of the glyphicon from symbol, changing the color of that glyphicon results in all instances of it changing color as well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion.
To change color of the glyphicon without influence on other glyphicons you should reset style of the glyphicon, not detaching from symbol.

Let me show:
Here we have two glyphicons and I want to change color of the bell.
[image]

Expand sybmol layer and select the inner shape. In the inspector view you will see current style for the shape:
[image]

Reset the style by selecting 'No Shared Style' from the list:
[image]

After that you can change color of the shape:
[image]

You can even create your own style, just select 'Create New Shared Style' from the list:  [image]

So you can apply your created style to other glyphicons:
[image]